# How to use SurfaceView to draw a single complex image

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am creating an Android App that produces random images based on complex mathematical expressions. The color of a pixel depends on its location and the expression chosen. (I have seen many iPhone apps that produce "random art" but relatively few Android apps.)

It takes 5 to 15 seconds for the image to be drawn on a Nexus S dev phone.

To keep the UI thread responsive this seems like the purpose of the `SurfaceView` class. Almost all the examples of `SurfaceView` deal with animation, not a single complex image. Once the image is done being drawn / rendered I won't change it until the user

So, is `SurfaceView` the right component to use? If so, can I get a callback from the `SurfaceView` or its internal thread when it is done drawing when it is done rendering the image? The callback is so I know it is okay to switch the low resolution and blocky version of the image art with the high resolution one?

Is there an alternative to `SurfaceView` that is better for complex rendering of single images. (Not animation.)

Cheers!

Comment: What is the advantage of using openGL (I assume a GLSurfaceView) over a regular SurfaceView?

Comment: Because the slowdown is not in the rendering but in the calculations. Offloading arbitrary mathematical calculations to GLSL shader language is... challenging :). Going the NDK route or using RenderScript's Compute API might be a better bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is render a single complex image on another thread to keep the UI responsive, then after it's done rendering actually draw it, you might consider just doing this in the standard keep-work-off-the-UI-thread way by using something like an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html). It's not like you're doing compositing or anything that really is GPU-specific (unless as others have suggested you can offload the actual rendering calculations to the GPU).

I would at least experiment with simply building an array representing your pixels in an `AsyncTask` then when you're done, create a bitmap with it using [`setPixels`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and set the source of an `ImageView` to that bitmap.

If on the other hand you want your image to appear pixel by pixel, then maybe `SurfaceView` might be a reasonable choice, in which case it'll basically be an animation so you can follow other tutorials. There's some other setup, but the main thing would be to override [`onDraw`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) and then you'll probably have to use [`Canvas.drawPoint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPoint%28float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to draw each pixel.